# A rational number is given in the form:

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A rational number is given in the form: $\frac{p}{q}$; $\frac{p}{q} \in (0,1)$ and $p$ and $q$ are coprime to each other. If $pq= 10!$ , what would be the number of ordered pairs $(p,q)$?

---

A beginning step would be noticing that $10!$ consist of $4$ primes $(2, 3, 5, 7)$. But how do I proceed? Taking combinations of two numbers from these $4$ primes doesn't seem right and making cases of this also doesn't yield the right result.

Comment: Your instincts are good, though I don't know what you mean by "combinations of $2$".  As you say, exactly one of $p,q$ must be divisible by $2$, and so on.

Comment: Yes, I realise that I could have been more clear while making that statement. By combinations of 2, I meant taking any two numbers from (2,3,5,7) but then there's a problem that this combination could contain the order pairs like  (5,2) which doesn't satisfy the condition of p/q being less than 1. How do we work with that?

Comment: Integers $p,q\in (0,1)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Ah, I ignored the bit about $p,q\in \{0,1\}$ because it didn't make any sense.  You meant to say that $\frac pq<1$?

Comment: If $p/q<1$, then inevitably $q/p>1$. This might give you a hint...

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm sorry I made a typo.

Comment: You didn't write $p/q$  you wrote $p,q$.  In any case:  use your approach to solve the problem without the condition on the size.  then argue that exactly half of your solutions pass the size test.

Comment: Note:  still ignoring the size constraint, there is no reason to choose just two of those primes. Taking $p=1$, $q=10!$ works.  Or,  If $10!=2^a3^b5^c7$  then taking $p=7$ and $q=2^a3^b5^c$ works.  And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is 8, but let me go through my reasoning. Since the numbers are coprime, you can't give one prime to both $p$ and $q$, as it seems you have realized. So, we are really counting the number of ways of assigning the primes $\{2,3,5,7\}$ to $p$ and $q$. This is equivalent to picking a subset of these numbers and assigning them to $p$ (the rest need to go to $q$). Thus, this would give us $2^4 = 16$ options. However, given such a pair $(p, q)$, exactly one of $q/p$ and $p/q$ is going to be in the desired range $(0, 1)$. Thus, we cut our options in half and we get 8 such ordered pairs $(p, q)$.

Comment: This is correct (+1).  You might want to point out that Unique Factorization precludes the possibility that $\frac pq=1$.

Comment: This is better than mine.  In yours you don't actually have to calculate the powers in the prime factorization of $10!$.  You know for each prime its "all or nothing"

Answer (score 1):

Figure out not just the prime factors of $10!$ but the powers as well...i.e. the complete prime factorization of $10!$.

$10!$ is a big (relatively speaking) number, but it's not a *monster*.  We *can* express it as $1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10 = 1*2*3*2^2*5*(2*3)*7*2^3*3^2*(2*5) = 2^8\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 7$

So if $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ and $pq = 2^8\cdot 3^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 7$ then

.... can you take it from here?...

> *Warning:  The following is free thinking so it will include indirect inefficient reasoning.  The point is to replicate how one would think about solving it; not haw to solve it in hindsight efficiently*

$p = 2^a3^b5^c7^d$ and $q= 2^{\alpha}3^{\beta}5^\gamma 7^{\delta}$

Where $a + \alpha = 8; b+\beta = 4; ...etc.....$

But as $\gcd(p,q) = 0$ we either have $a=0$ or $\alpha = 0$ and $b =0$ or $\beta = 0$ etc.

In other word we have $p = 2^{0,8}3^{0,4}5^{0,2}7^{0,1}$ while $q=2^{8,0}3^{4,0}5^{2,0}7^{1,0}$.

So there is two choices for $a:  0$ or $8$; all or nothing.  Same for the other variables.  And $\alpha, \beta, $ etc are completely dependent $a,b,c,d$.

So there are $2^4 = 16$ options.

> *In hindsight, it be better to answer*

If $pq = 10!$ then $q = \frac {10!}p$ so we only have to calculate howmany choices of $p$ there are.

$p = 2^a3^b5^c7^d$ and $q = 2^{8-a}3^{4-b}5^{2-c}7^{1-d}$.  But as $\gcd(p,q)=1$ for each variable either $a =0$ or $8-a=0$ etc so there are $2$ options only.

So $p = 2^{0|8}3^{0|4}5^{0|2}7^{0|1}$ so there are four choices each with $2$ options.

So there $2^4=16$ choices.

.....

Oh.... I overlooked $\frac pq < 1$.

Oh well.  There are $16$ *ordered* pairs total.  As $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ (or because $10!$ is not a perfect square) we can't have $p < q$ and so there are $\frac {16}2=8$ *unordered* pairs or in other words pairs where $p < q$.

====

Actually in hind-hindsight it's better to answer as Eyob Tsegaye did and realize it's enought to know $10! =2^m3^n5^s7^t$ and $p$ and $q$ have those powers as "all or nothing" and not *have* to figure the actual prime factorization.